# Change postfix limit size of file attachment for some user

Tags: postfix, email-server

I'm using postfix as a relay server and using SASL as authentication. In my case, I want to set a different limit for some SASL user and the others will be using the default limit of postfix. Based on this link https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mail/postfix-attachment-size/, I know that it is possible to change maximum file attachment using configuration 'message_size_limit', but what I want to know is set different 'message_size_limit' configuration for some SASL user. Is it possible to doing so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be possible, but only with an plugin service like policyd.  This can make rules dynamically such as sending limits, etc.

https://wiki.policyd.org/